# mongodb sharding - launch mongos with mongos.conf

Tags: configuration, mongodb, sharding

We are currently setting up a sharded cluster with MongoDB, config servers have been set up using a configuration file : **mongod.conf** pointing out alternative paths for data and logs folders :

```
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: "/home/mongo/logs/mongod.log"
   logAppend: true
storage:
   journal:
      enabled: true
      dbpath: "/home/mongo/data"
processManagement:
   fork: true
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27019

sharding:
   clusterRole:configsvr
```

Using the docs (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/), I've seen that it is possible to launch mongos using a similar file, problem is, I don't know if this file should be different from mongod.conf. So far I have not seen anyone use a mongos.conf file...

Should the file be identical? 
Just changing paths, port and clusterRole?
And adding a "configDB:" lign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [you use a configuration file for the `mongos`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/configuration-options/#use-the-configuration-file), and many of the options are the same for the `mongos` as the `mongod`. You will need to [consult the MongoDB configuration file options documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/configuration-options/) for more explicit instructions on which options are viable for which MongoDB server role. I see that you already found that link, but all your answers are there.

When launching the `mongos` (by hand or in your init script) you feed it the config file as a runtime parameter. You will need to tell the `mongos` things like what port to run on, the logpath (if you log out), and most importantly `configdb=[your config server URIs]` and your replica set key.

Comment: Ok then, I'll keep that in mind, thank you very much!